mdadm - can't add back replaced drive due to "does not have a valid v1.2 superblock, not importing" error
I have an existing raid 6 array where one of the drives failed but, when I try to replace it using mdadm --manage /dev/md1 --add /dev/sde3, mdadm errors and I get the following message in the kernel log:
md: sde3 does not have a valid v1.2 superblock, not importing!

Note that I have zeroed the replacement drive and repeatedly zeroed the superblock using mdadm --zero-superblock -e 1.2 --force /dev/sde3.  It may be relevant that the add seems to write a new superblock to the drive, marking the drive as Spare but it doesn't actually add it to the array.
I think the mistake that I made is that I removed the failed drive using mdadm --manage md1 --remove /dev/sde3 after it had failed and before trying to add the replacement.
I have tried various combinations of zeroing the replacement drive's superblock and assembling the array with or without the replacement drive but they all fail with the same error.
At this point, I think my only option is the recreate the array using --assume-clean and marking the failed slot as missing.
Here is the information for the array:
/dev/md1:
           Version : 1.2
     Creation Time : Sun May 12 20:28:14 2013
        Raid Level : raid6
        Array Size : 22686329856 (21.13 TiB 23.23 TB)
     Used Dev Size : 3781054976 (3.52 TiB 3.87 TB)
      Raid Devices : 8
     Total Devices : 7
       Persistence : Superblock is persistent

       Update Time : Mon Sep 30 17:28:13 2024
             State : clean, degraded 
    Active Devices : 7
   Working Devices : 7
    Failed Devices : 0
     Spare Devices : 0

            Layout : left-symmetric
        Chunk Size : 512K

Consistency Policy : resync

              Name : playroom:raid  (local to host playroom)
              UUID : 34484e2b:99dc0604:10b071d5:c8012127
            Events : 176577

    Number   Major   Minor   RaidDevice State
      13       8       99        0      active sync   /dev/sdg3
      10       8      115        1      active sync   /dev/sdh3
      11       8       19        2      active sync   /dev/sdb3
       -       0        0        3      removed
       9       8       83        4      active sync   /dev/sdf3
       8       8       51        5      active sync   /dev/sdd3
      15       8       35        6      active sync   /dev/sdc3
      14       8        3        7      active sync   /dev/sda3

/dev/sda3:
          Magic : a92b4efc
        Version : 1.2
    Feature Map : 0x8
     Array UUID : 34484e2b:99dc0604:10b071d5:c8012127
           Name : playroom:raid  (local to host playroom)
  Creation Time : Sun May 12 20:28:14 2013
     Raid Level : raid6
   Raid Devices : 8

 Avail Dev Size : 7562110607 sectors (3.52 TiB 3.87 TB)
     Array Size : 22686329856 KiB (21.13 TiB 23.23 TB)
  Used Dev Size : 7562109952 sectors (3.52 TiB 3.87 TB)
    Data Offset : 262144 sectors
   Super Offset : 8 sectors
   Unused Space : before=262064 sectors, after=655 sectors
          State : clean
    Device UUID : b3b21814:7f42ad3f:cb7e8d5b:5dfd0d22

    Update Time : Mon Sep 30 17:28:13 2024
  Bad Block Log : 512 entries available at offset 16 sectors - bad blocks present.
       Checksum : ef2d77c6 - correct
         Events : 176577

         Layout : left-symmetric
     Chunk Size : 512K

   Device Role : Active device 7
   Array State : AAA.AAAA ('A' == active, '.' == missing, 'R' == replacing)

/dev/sdb3:
          Magic : a92b4efc
        Version : 1.2
    Feature Map : 0x8
     Array UUID : 34484e2b:99dc0604:10b071d5:c8012127
           Name : playroom:raid  (local to host playroom)
  Creation Time : Sun May 12 20:28:14 2013
     Raid Level : raid6
   Raid Devices : 8

 Avail Dev Size : 7562110607 sectors (3.52 TiB 3.87 TB)
     Array Size : 22686329856 KiB (21.13 TiB 23.23 TB)
  Used Dev Size : 7562109952 sectors (3.52 TiB 3.87 TB)
    Data Offset : 262144 sectors
   Super Offset : 8 sectors
   Unused Space : before=262064 sectors, after=655 sectors
          State : clean
    Device UUID : 77d07ff9:e5a670c0:cfb45916:717b98e8

    Update Time : Mon Sep 30 17:28:13 2024
  Bad Block Log : 512 entries available at offset 16 sectors - bad blocks present.
       Checksum : d6aeae07 - correct
         Events : 176577

         Layout : left-symmetric
     Chunk Size : 512K

   Device Role : Active device 2
   Array State : AAA.AAAA ('A' == active, '.' == missing, 'R' == replacing)

/dev/sdc3:
          Magic : a92b4efc
        Version : 1.2
    Feature Map : 0x8
     Array UUID : 34484e2b:99dc0604:10b071d5:c8012127
           Name : playroom:raid  (local to host playroom)
  Creation Time : Sun May 12 20:28:14 2013
     Raid Level : raid6
   Raid Devices : 8

 Avail Dev Size : 7562110607 sectors (3.52 TiB 3.87 TB)
     Array Size : 22686329856 KiB (21.13 TiB 23.23 TB)
  Used Dev Size : 7562109952 sectors (3.52 TiB 3.87 TB)
    Data Offset : 262144 sectors
   Super Offset : 8 sectors
   Unused Space : before=262064 sectors, after=655 sectors
          State : clean
    Device UUID : 67b4abd6:f1e5b87f:0851dd21:9200e1b6

    Update Time : Mon Sep 30 17:28:13 2024
  Bad Block Log : 512 entries available at offset 16 sectors - bad blocks present.
       Checksum : 4ceee719 - correct
         Events : 176577

         Layout : left-symmetric
     Chunk Size : 512K

   Device Role : Active device 6
   Array State : AAA.AAAA ('A' == active, '.' == missing, 'R' == replacing)

/dev/sdd3:
          Magic : a92b4efc
        Version : 1.2
    Feature Map : 0x8
     Array UUID : 34484e2b:99dc0604:10b071d5:c8012127
           Name : playroom:raid  (local to host playroom)
  Creation Time : Sun May 12 20:28:14 2013
     Raid Level : raid6
   Raid Devices : 8

 Avail Dev Size : 7562110607 sectors (3.52 TiB 3.87 TB)
     Array Size : 22686329856 KiB (21.13 TiB 23.23 TB)
  Used Dev Size : 7562109952 sectors (3.52 TiB 3.87 TB)
    Data Offset : 262144 sectors
   Super Offset : 8 sectors
   Unused Space : before=262064 sectors, after=655 sectors
          State : clean
    Device UUID : fe728bca:23485bc8:a5e5ac21:73c1a89a

    Update Time : Mon Sep 30 17:28:13 2024
  Bad Block Log : 512 entries available at offset 16 sectors - bad blocks present.
       Checksum : 6d085d59 - correct
         Events : 176577

         Layout : left-symmetric
     Chunk Size : 512K

   Device Role : Active device 5
   Array State : AAA.AAAA ('A' == active, '.' == missing, 'R' == replacing)

/dev/sde3:
          Magic : a92b4efc
        Version : 1.2
    Feature Map : 0x8
     Array UUID : 34484e2b:99dc0604:10b071d5:c8012127
           Name : playroom:raid  (local to host playroom)
  Creation Time : Sun May 12 20:28:14 2013
     Raid Level : raid6
   Raid Devices : 8

 Avail Dev Size : 7562110607 sectors (3.52 TiB 3.87 TB)
     Array Size : 22686329856 KiB (21.13 TiB 23.23 TB)
  Used Dev Size : 7562109952 sectors (3.52 TiB 3.87 TB)
    Data Offset : 262144 sectors
   Super Offset : 8 sectors
   Unused Space : before=261864 sectors, after=655 sectors
          State : clean
    Device UUID : 16c61ab0:553c3ce5:d9b300b8:54b4fe14

    Update Time : Mon Sep 30 17:28:13 2024
  Bad Block Log : 512 entries available at offset 264 sectors - bad blocks present.
       Checksum : 801fb4f3 - correct
         Events : 0

         Layout : left-symmetric
     Chunk Size : 512K

   Device Role : spare
   Array State : AAA.AAAA ('A' == active, '.' == missing, 'R' == replacing)

/dev/sdf3:
          Magic : a92b4efc
        Version : 1.2
    Feature Map : 0x8
     Array UUID : 34484e2b:99dc0604:10b071d5:c8012127
           Name : playroom:raid  (local to host playroom)
  Creation Time : Sun May 12 20:28:14 2013
     Raid Level : raid6
   Raid Devices : 8

 Avail Dev Size : 7562110607 sectors (3.52 TiB 3.87 TB)
     Array Size : 22686329856 KiB (21.13 TiB 23.23 TB)
  Used Dev Size : 7562109952 sectors (3.52 TiB 3.87 TB)
    Data Offset : 262144 sectors
   Super Offset : 8 sectors
   Unused Space : before=261864 sectors, after=655 sectors
          State : clean
    Device UUID : a8368569:56a9356f:e158fc12:9a75fcf4

    Update Time : Mon Sep 30 17:28:13 2024
  Bad Block Log : 512 entries available at offset 264 sectors - bad blocks present.
       Checksum : fe7faa91 - correct
         Events : 176577

         Layout : left-symmetric
     Chunk Size : 512K

   Device Role : Active device 4
   Array State : AAA.AAAA ('A' == active, '.' == missing, 'R' == replacing)

/dev/sdg3:
          Magic : a92b4efc
        Version : 1.2
    Feature Map : 0x8
     Array UUID : 34484e2b:99dc0604:10b071d5:c8012127
           Name : playroom:raid  (local to host playroom)
  Creation Time : Sun May 12 20:28:14 2013
     Raid Level : raid6
   Raid Devices : 8

 Avail Dev Size : 7562110607 sectors (3.52 TiB 3.87 TB)
     Array Size : 22686329856 KiB (21.13 TiB 23.23 TB)
  Used Dev Size : 7562109952 sectors (3.52 TiB 3.87 TB)
    Data Offset : 262144 sectors
   Super Offset : 8 sectors
   Unused Space : before=262064 sectors, after=655 sectors
          State : clean
    Device UUID : 4b25f2f9:65988664:86916d97:f0e3ac2a

    Update Time : Mon Sep 30 17:28:13 2024
  Bad Block Log : 512 entries available at offset 16 sectors - bad blocks present.
       Checksum : 3e5f2e4b - correct
         Events : 176577

         Layout : left-symmetric
     Chunk Size : 512K

   Device Role : Active device 0
   Array State : AAA.AAAA ('A' == active, '.' == missing, 'R' == replacing)

/dev/sdh3:
          Magic : a92b4efc
        Version : 1.2
    Feature Map : 0x8
     Array UUID : 34484e2b:99dc0604:10b071d5:c8012127
           Name : playroom:raid  (local to host playroom)
  Creation Time : Sun May 12 20:28:14 2013
     Raid Level : raid6
   Raid Devices : 8

 Avail Dev Size : 7562110607 sectors (3.52 TiB 3.87 TB)
     Array Size : 22686329856 KiB (21.13 TiB 23.23 TB)
  Used Dev Size : 7562109952 sectors (3.52 TiB 3.87 TB)
    Data Offset : 262144 sectors
   Super Offset : 8 sectors
   Unused Space : before=261864 sectors, after=655 sectors
          State : clean
    Device UUID : 948d0c31:03c19927:22f18cdd:0d84ffb2

    Update Time : Mon Sep 30 17:28:13 2024
  Bad Block Log : 512 entries available at offset 264 sectors - bad blocks present.
       Checksum : 6fec028 - correct
         Events : 176577

         Layout : left-symmetric
     Chunk Size : 512K

   Device Role : Active device 1
   Array State : AAA.AAAA ('A' == active, '.' == missing, 'R' == replacing)

cat /proc/mdstat produces:
md1 : active raid6 sdg3[13] sda3[14] sdc3[15] sdd3[8] sdf3[9] sdb3[11] sdh3[10]
      22686329856 blocks super 1.2 level 6, 512k chunk, algorithm 2 [8/7] [UUU_UUUU]

unused devices: <none>

Thanks to frostschutz for spotting the bad blocks inconsistency.  The mdadm --examine-badblocks dump is:
Bad-blocks on /dev/sda3:
             3834808 for 512 sectors
             3835320 for 368 sectors
          1787061064 for 16 sectors
          1788696152 for 8 sectors
Bad-blocks on /dev/sdb3:
             3834808 for 512 sectors
             3835320 for 368 sectors
          1787061064 for 16 sectors
          1788696152 for 8 sectors
Bad-blocks on /dev/sdc3:
          1787061064 for 16 sectors
          1788696152 for 8 sectors
Bad-blocks on /dev/sdd3:
             3834808 for 512 sectors
             3835320 for 368 sectors
          1787061064 for 16 sectors
          1788696152 for 8 sectors
Bad-blocks on /dev/sde3:
                   0 for 0 sectors
                   --- repeats for 512 lines ---
Bad-blocks on /dev/sdf3:
          1787061064 for 16 sectors
          1788696152 for 8 sectors
Bad-blocks on /dev/sdg3:
          1787061064 for 16 sectors
          1788696152 for 8 sectors
Bad-blocks on /dev/sdh3:
          1787061064 for 16 sectors
          1788696152 for 8 sectors


Which kernel and mdadm version are you using? There seems to be something going on with the bad block log as well, show mdadm --examine-badblocks for all? /proc/mdstat? If all share the same bad blocks, your md will produce read errors. And will continue doing so even if you replace all drives.

The kernel is 6.8.0-45-generic (Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS) and madm version is v4.3 - 2024-02-15 - Ubuntu 4.3-1ubuntu2.1.

I have add the examine-badblocks and /proc/mdstat output to the question.

OK, so this should be a kernel bug. For some reason, the kernel prevents adding devices here.
As a workaround, get rid of the bad block log:
mdadm --zero-superblock /dev/sdx3 # your missing drive (sde3? check!)
mdadm --stop /dev/mdX
mdadm --assemble /dev/mdX --update=force-no-bbl /dev/sd…
mdadm /dev/mdX --add /dev/sdx3

You kind of have to remove the bad block log anyway, since those bad blocks aren't going away otherwise (not when more than redundancy drives share the same bad blocks, which happens to be the case). The bad block log is kind of a semi-broken feature…
Data in these sectors (as shown by --examine-badblocks) may not be in sync and may not hold correct data at all, so watch out for some potential data corruption there.
Also check your logs if you can find out what triggered these bad blocks, and do a SMART check for your drives just in case, the bad blocks are actually physical.
After removing the bad block log, adding devices should work again or at least did for me when I tested locally.
If it still doesn't work, you'd have to discuss this with the developers on linux-raid mailing list (try it with current kernel first).

Once the issue with the drive is solved, run mdadm with --action=check to detect mismatches in the array. If there are any, unless you want to recover mismatched sectors in a raid array (old question — not a very good answer), follow it up with mdadm --action=repair.
Leaving mismatches in a raid456 array uncorrected can cause data corruption in the long term since they don't necessarily get corrected with new writes, either.

Thanks for the comments and advice.  I had pretty much resigned myself to having to recreate the array and, luckily, I happen to have an old QNAP lying around with enough space to backup the whole array.  I am in the process of backing up the array's contents which looks like it'll take a couple of days (the QNAP is slow and only supports a 1MB connection).

That should have been a 100MB connection and I suspect the bad blocks are a hold over from previous drive problems and replacements.
Once I have a complete backup, I'll test your solution but then I'll just wipe the array and restore everything from the backup.
I'll let you know whether or not your solution works.

Destroying the bad block list resolved the problem.
